# What text editor will not overload my Xubuntu 13.10?

Tags: xubuntu, text-editor

I don't do a lot of it, but I need to edit some html files and need a text editor to do it. I liked the looks of Kate but someone in the forum said Kate would be a big download for me because I'm Xubuntu. And since I've converted an old Dell with only a 40 GB HD, and I don't really need a feature-laden text editor, I'm not eager to overload it. Just a text editor that plays nice with Xubuntu 13.10 will do.

I've heard good things about Bluefish. Will that not overload my Xubuntu 13.10?

Comment: Try nano...or Leafpad

Comment: You are going to end up with a bunch of recommendations :)

Comment: Mousepad is preinstalled in Xubuntu and can be launched from the Accessories menu, could you clarify why it does not satisfy your requirements?

Comment: I did not know Mousepad was a text editor. I will investigate it. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

[Scribes](http://scribes.sourceforge.net/download.html) or just plain and simple `gedit` should do the trick on an Xubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You have default `gedit` editor inbuilt and it is quite good i thin if you are over loaded then `gedit` is good enough for `html` editing or you can use `sublime text 3` as the look and fill is quite good as it made for mac.